# "Number of query values and destination fields are not the same" error on INSERT

Tags: ms-access-2010, vb.net-2010

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class form7
    Dim inc As Integer
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim dbprovider As String
    Dim dbsource As String
    Dim str As String
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim TotalRows As Integer
    Dim ID_Number As Integer

    Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Bank\db1.accdb ")
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM accountsTable", con)
        Dim totalRows As Long = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        TextBox1.Text = totalRows + 1000
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Form5.Show()

        dbprovider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; dbsource=Data Source=D:\Bank\db1.accdb"
        MsgBox("Database is now open")

        str = "Insert into accountsTable (Account_Number, First_Name, Midle_Name, Last_Name, Date_of_birth, Occupation, Age, Marital_Status, Address, City, Country, State, Account_Type, Pin_Code, Mobile_Number, Email_ID, Opening_Balance) values ('" &
           TextBox1.Text & "','" &
           TextBox2.Text & "','" &
           TextBox3.Text & "','" &
           TextBox4.Text & "','" &
           DateTimePicker1.Value & "','" &
           TextBox6.Text & "','" &
           TextBox7.Text & "','" &
           TextBox8.Text & "','" &
           TextBox9.Text & "','" &
           ComboBox1.Text & "','" &
           ComboBox2.Text & "','" &
           ComboBox3.Text & "','" &
           ComboBox4.Text & "','" &
           TextBox10.Text & "','" &
           TextBox11.Text & "','" &
           TextBox12.Text & "','" &
           TextBox13.Text & "','" & "')"

        cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(str, con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Record is inserted")
        con.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""
        TextBox3.Text = ""
        TextBox4.Text = ""
        DateTimePicker1.Value = ""
        TextBox6.Text = ""
        TextBox7.Text = ""
        TextBox8.Text = ""
        TextBox9.Text = ""
        ComboBox1.Text = ""
        ComboBox2.Text = ""
        ComboBox3.Text = ""
        ComboBox4.Text = ""
        TextBox10.Text = ""
        TextBox11.Text = ""
        TextBox12.Text = ""
        TextBox13.Text = ""

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Me.Close()
        Form3.Show()
    End Sub

End Class
```

The error happens here :

```
cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(str, con)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()  ' <-- error here
MsgBox("Record is inserted")
con.Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 17 columns in your columns list, but you are adding an extra (18th) zero-length string value onto the end of your VALUES list:

```
TextBox13.Text & "','" & "')"
                   ^^^^^^^^
```

You really should be using a *parameterized query*, something more like this:

```vb
str = 
        "Insert into accountsTable (Account_Number, First_Name, Midle_Name, Last_Name, Date_of_birth, Occupation, Age, Marital_Status, Address, City, Country, State, Account_Type, Pin_Code, Mobile_Number, Email_ID, Opening_Balance) " &
        "values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(str, con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox1.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox2.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox3.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox4.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", DateTimePicker1.Value)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox6.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox7.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox8.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox9.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", ComboBox1.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", ComboBox2.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", ComboBox3.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", ComboBox4.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox10.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox11.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox12.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox13.Text)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Note that if some of those TextBox controls may be empty then you'll have to check the length of their `.Text` properties and possibly insert a null value instead. For example, for "Opening_Balance" you may need to do something like

```vb
If TextBox13.Text.Length = 0 Then
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", DBNull.Value)
Else
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Convert.ToDecimal(TextBox13.Text))
End If
```

Comment: Dear Gord, I add this one but it shows me (Data type mismatch in criteria expression.) instead of showing me the previous problem . could u help me please.